# In Google Sheets, how can one aggregate values (MAX, MIN, AVERAGE) based on the result of splitting a string in a different column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

If I had a table with the following values, how can I generate the following table? The result table separates out each tag and calculates the number of rows with the tag mentioned (COUNT) and also the max value for a given tag.

```
    +-----+-------------+
    | VAL | TAGS        |
    +-----+-------------+
    |  4  | html, css   | 
    +-----+-------------+
    |  2  | js, ts      |
    +-----+-------------+
    |  3  | js, css     |
    +-----+-------------+
```

```
    +------+-------+-------+
    | TAG  | COUNT |  MAX  |
    +------+-------+-------+
    | html |   1   |   4   |
    +------+-------+-------+
    | css  |   2   |   4   |
    +------+-------+-------+
    | js   |   2   |   3   |
    +------+-------+-------+
    | ts   |   1   |   2   |
    +------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B3:B, ","))<>"", "♀"&A3:A&"♦"&SPLIT(
 SUBSTITUTE(B3:B, ", ", ","), ",")&"♦", )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♀")), "♦"), 
 "select Col2,count(Col1),avg(Col1),max(Col1),min(Col1) 
  group by Col2
  label Col2'tags'"))
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow, that is a gnarly formula!  But it looks like it works. I actually ended up implementing a solution using custom formulas. Do you think your solution would be faster or slower?

Comment: depends... on such a small sample it doesn't matter - speed wise it would be the same.

Comment: That was just a sample I created for the question, the real dataset has hundreds of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use formula like this:

```
=query (
   arrayformula (
      split (
         transpose (
            split (
               textjoin (
                     ",",true, 
                     arrayformula (
                         {filter(A90:A,A90:A<>"") & "✫" & 
                          trim(split(filter(B90:B,A90:A<>""),","))
                         }
                     )
               ),",")
            ),"✫"
         )
      ), 
   "select Col2, count(Col2), max(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col2  label Col2 'Tag'")
```

[image]